# Any ideas what I am doing wrong when trying to store json from webservice into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I am using webservice to pull out some information in json format. I am able to view them in my app. However when I try to store them in dictionary i keep getting error saying value "courseId" not compliant. This is what I have

```
 NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (id courseDictionary in response)  {

    ListOfCourses *course = [[ListOfCourses alloc] initWithDictionary:courseDictionary];
    [results addObject:course];

  }
```

and in my ListOfCourses.m I have

```
 - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
 {

  self = [super init];
  if (self) {

    _courseId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dictionary valueForKey:@"courseId"] 
    _room1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"room1"];
    _subjectCode = [dictionary objectForKey:@"subjectCode"];

   }
  return self;

 }
```

json file

```
    {
   "Template":{
      "Room1":"Day 1 room name/number; string; required; 10 characters",
    "SubjectId":"Subject identifier; number; required; Subject identifier must exist",

    {
   "Links":[
      {
         "Rel":"self",
         "Href":"/api/courses/2"
      },
      {
         "Rel":"collection",
         "Href":"/api/courses/"
      }
   ],
   "Item":{
      "Link":{
         "Rel":"self",
         "Href":"/api/courses/2"
      },
      "Id":1,
      "SubjectCode":"D9920",
      "Room1":"S2153"

}
```

UPDATED: I am returning a collection of objects, when i do this

```
 _courses = (NSArray *)[response objectForKey:@"Collection"];
```

I am able to view the objects. I am trying to put them each individually into dictionary now

Comment: can you post the error log please?

Comment: It's (very) unclear what you're doing, but at the very least could you include the code you've cut off on the right margin?

Comment: are you getting error in this line?    _courseId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dictionary valueForKey:@"courseId"];

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre - That line's been cut off -- we don't know what is beyond the ";" that you added.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Is your server sending this string?

Comment: Ok i found the problem, I am returning a collection of items. I am trying to extract each item individually and put them in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Change your line of code from:

`_courseId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dictionary valueForKey:@"courseId"`]

to:

```
_courseId = [NSNumber numberWithInt[[dictionary  valueForKey:@"Id"] intValue]];
```

If this won't help please post the json file.

//EDITED

You use [dictionary valueForKey:@"courseId"] but the key is Id, please change courseId to Id.

//EXTENDED

You have dictionary embedded in dictionary try this:

```
    NSDictionary *dic = dictionary[@"Item"];
    _courseId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[dic[@"Id"] intValue]];
    _room1 = dict[@"Room1"];
    _subjectCode = dict[@"SubjectCode"];
```

If it doesn't work you have to post beginning of your json file.

Comment: Tried that I still get this [<__NSCFString 0x8368810> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Id.'

Comment: Can you post beginning of your json?

Comment: i am going to try that, beginning of the json has been posted

Comment: Should use `objectForKey:` not `valuerForKey:`

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking entities on and off a stream, you should use the NSCoding protocol. There are many ways to do that with JSON, e.g. [JSONCoding](https://github.com/ontometrics/JSONCoding).

These types of problems would qualify as refactor smells: you should not have to worry about how something was bundled up.